# What is the state of a Lock after Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization

Given is the following code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Data
{
    private int value;

    Data (int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class InfoCollection implements Serializable
{
    private Data[] data;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private transient ReentrantLock _lock = new ReentrantLock ();

    public InfoCollection (int datasize)
    {
        this.data = new Data[datasize];
    }

    public setData (Data newdata, int index)
    {
        _lock.lock ();

        try
        {
            this.data[index] = newdata;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.unlock ();
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I create an object of type `InfoCollection` and serialize it. After a while I deserialize it and want to use it. After deserialization, in what state will the `_lock` field be ? Locked or unlocked ? null or not null ? Why ?

This can be easily found out by actually doing it and check the lock's state, but I want to figure it out logically.

I'm thinking that, after deserialization, the loading of the class/object will trigger a call to the constructor of `ReentrantLock` (because the constructor is called outside of any method/constructor), which will give you an unlocked object as result. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example lock will be null.

_lock - in transient - it is not stored - so it will be not restored. Constructor will not be called

private **transient** ReentrantLock _lock = new ReentrantLock ();

(
**NOTE**

Data is not serializable, you do not have method implemented:

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
     throws IOException
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

)

Comment: yes, I forgot to make `Data` serializable. My bad. Let's assume it is marked as Serializable. How can I make `_lock` not null after deserialization WITHOUT giving external access to `_lock` ? I know I could just remove the `transient` keyword. But does it actually make sense to serialize a Lock ?

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc for `ReentrantLock` in JDK 1.5 states explicitly that:

```
 *
 * <p>Serialization of this class behaves in the same way as built-in
 * locks: a deserialized lock is in the unlocked state, regardless of
 * its state when serialized.
```